# how to mysql connection error in online powerbi

Tags: powerbi

I use two datasources
one xls file generated from Exsion, stored locally
one mysql database somewhere online
I have the personal connector installed my desktop and the desktop is 24/7 on

Everything works in the Powerbi Desktop setup

after publishing, in app.powerbi.com the link to the xls file, using the personal connector works flawless

the data from the MYSQL database online cant be refreshed.
Follwoing error is received:

```
Cannot connect to the mashup data source. See error details for more information.Hide details
Underlying error code:  -2147467259 Table: DCN Pivot_Status.
Underlying error message:   MySQL: Kan geen databaseprovider met invariante naam MySql.Data.MySqlClient vinden. Deze fout treedt mogelijk op doordat providerspecifieke clientsoftware is vereist, maar niet is geïnstalleerd op deze computer. Als u clientsoftware voor deze provider wilt downloaden, gaat u naar de volgende site en kiest u de 64-bits (x64) versie die minimaal MySQL Connector/Net is:
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Do you have a data gateway set up so the service can connect to your SQL server?

Comment: The mysql server is online on the internet (not the office) and accessible from anywhere. don't think it is necessary to have one?
I do use a gateway to link to my locally stored xls though

Comment: If it's not internal, then I think you're right. Does it require credentials to access though, or is it completely open where you don't need a username and password?

Comment: password / username required.